# Android Lazy Loading List - retrieve images dynamically (MySQL & JSON)

Tags: android

I am new to Android.

I want to get the values of drk_image or TAG_DRK_IMAGE from the HashMap and store it to ***private String[ ] drinkImages***. Is this possible?

**Code:**

**Lazy_ListItem.java**

```
public class Lazy_ListItem extends Activity {

ListView list;
Lazy_Adapter adapter;

// Creating JSON Parser object
JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();

ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> drinksList;

// url to get all drinks list
private static String url_all_drinks = "http://10.0.2.2/restosnapp/get_all_products.php";

// JSON Node names
private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
private static final String TAG_DRINKS = "drinks";
private static final String TAG_DRK_IMAGE = "drk_image";

// drinks JSONArray
JSONArray drinks = null;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.list_item);

    list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
    adapter = new Lazy_Adapter(this, drinkImages);
    list.setAdapter(adapter);

}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    list.setAdapter(null);
    super.onDestroy();
}

/**
 * Background Async Task to Load all drinks by making HTTP Request
 * */
class LoadAllProducts extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    /**
     * getting All drinks from url
     * */
    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
        // Building Parameters
        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        // getting JSON string from URL
        JSONObject json = jParser.makeHttpRequest(url_all_drinks, "GET",
                params);

        // Check your log cat for JSON response
        Log.d("All Drinks: ", json.toString());

        try {
            // Checking for SUCCESS TAG
            int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

            if (success == 1) {
                // drinks found
                // Getting Array of Drinks
                drinks = json.getJSONArray(TAG_DRINKS);

                // looping through All Drinks
                for (int i = 0; i < drinks.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject c = drinks.getJSONObject(i);

                    // Storing each json item in variable
                    String drk_image = c.getString(TAG_DRK_IMAGE);

                    // creating new HashMap
                    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                    // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                    map.put(TAG_DRK_IMAGE, drk_image);

                    // adding HashList to ArrayList
                    drinksList.add(map);

                }
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }
}

private String[] drinkImages = {
        "http://webitprojects.com/restaurant/images/drinks/drk_coffee.jpg",
        "http://webitprojects.com/restaurant/images/drinks/drk_calamansijuice.jpg",
        "http://webitprojects.com/restaurant/images/drinks/drk_blackgulaman.jpg",
        "http://webitprojects.com/restaurant/images/drinks/drk_avocadoshake.jpg",
        "http://webitprojects.com/restaurant/images/drinks/drk_durianshake.jpg" }; }
```

The value of ***String[ ] drinkImages*** must be replaced with values from the HashMap (from the database) and so I can pass it to Lazy_Adapter.

I want to get the values from the database instead of just declaring it like this:

```
private String[] drinkImages = {
        "http://webitprojects.com/restaurant/images/drinks/drk_coffee.jpg",
        "http://webitprojects.com/restaurant/images/drinks/drk_calamansijuice.jpg",
        "http://webitprojects.com/restaurant/images/drinks/drk_blackgulaman.jpg",
        "http://webitprojects.com/restaurant/images/drinks/drk_avocadoshake.jpg",
        "http://webitprojects.com/restaurant/images/drinks/drk_durianshake.jpg" };
```

**Lazy_Adapter.java**

```
public class Lazy_Adapter extends BaseAdapter {

String drk_name, drk_desc, drk_price, drk_avail;

// Progress Dialog
private ProgressDialog pDialog;

// Creating JSON Parser object
JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();

ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> drinksList;

// url to get all drinks list
private static String url_all_drinks = "http://10.0.2.2/restosnapp/get_all_products.php";

// JSON Node names
private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
private static final String TAG_DRINKS = "drinks";
private static final String TAG_RID = "rid";
private static final String TAG_DRK_ID = "drk_id";
private static final String TAG_DRK_NAME = "drk_name";
private static final String TAG_DRK_DESC = "drk_desc";
private static final String TAG_DRK_PRICE = "drk_price";
private static final String TAG_DRK_AVAIL = "drk_avail";
private static final String TAG_DRK_IMAGE = "drk_image";

// drinks JSONArray
JSONArray drinks = null;

private Activity activity;
private String[] data;
private static LayoutInflater inflater = null;
public Lazy_ImageLoader imageLoader;

public Lazy_Adapter(Activity a, String[] d) {
    activity = a;
    data = d;
    inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    imageLoader = new Lazy_ImageLoader(activity.getApplicationContext());

    // Hashmap for ListView
    drinksList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

    // Loading drinks in Background Thread
    new LoadAllProducts().execute();
}

public int getCount() {
    return data.length;
}

public Object getItem(int position) {
    return position;
}

public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

// ///

/**
 * Background Async Task to Load all drinks by making HTTP Request
 * */
class LoadAllProducts extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    /**
     * getting All drinks from url
     * */
    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
        // Building Parameters
        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        // getting JSON string from URL
        JSONObject json = jParser.makeHttpRequest(url_all_drinks, "GET",
                params);

        // Check your log cat for JSON response
        Log.d("All Drinks: ", json.toString());

        try {
            // Checking for SUCCESS TAG
            int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

            if (success == 1) {
                // drinks found
                // Getting Array of Drinks
                drinks = json.getJSONArray(TAG_DRINKS);

                // looping through All Drinks
                for (int i = 0; i < drinks.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject c = drinks.getJSONObject(i);

                    // Storing each json item in variable
                    drk_name = c.getString(TAG_DRK_NAME);
                    drk_desc = c.getString(TAG_DRK_DESC);
                    drk_price = c.getString(TAG_DRK_PRICE);
                    drk_avail = c.getString(TAG_DRK_AVAIL);

                    // creating new HashMap
                    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                    // adding each child node to HashMap key => value

                    map.put(TAG_DRK_NAME, drk_name);
                    map.put(TAG_DRK_DESC, drk_desc);
                    map.put(TAG_DRK_PRICE, drk_price);
                    map.put(TAG_DRK_AVAIL, drk_avail);

                    // adding HashList to ArrayList
                    drinksList.add(map);
                }
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

}

@SuppressWarnings("unused")
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View vi = convertView;
    if (convertView == null)
        vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item, null);

    for (Map<String, String> menuItem : drinksList) {
        ImageView image = (ImageView) vi.findViewById(R.id.image);
        imageLoader.DisplayImage(data[position], image);
        TextView tvMenuName = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.tvMenuName);
        tvMenuName.setText(drinksList.get(position).get(TAG_DRK_NAME));
        TextView tvMenuDesc = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.tvMenuDesc);
        tvMenuDesc.setText(drinksList.get(position).get(TAG_DRK_DESC));
        TextView tvMenuPrice = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.tvMenuPrice);
        tvMenuPrice.setText("P"
                + drinksList.get(position).get(TAG_DRK_PRICE));
        TextView tvMenuAvail = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.tvMenuAvail);
        tvMenuAvail.setText(drinksList.get(position).get(TAG_DRK_AVAIL));

    }

    return vi;
}}
```

EDIT:

**Output:**

This is the output if I have declared ***private String[] drinkImages***. I am hoping to get the same output when getting it from the database.

[Emulator Screenshot](http://i1062.photobucket.com/albums/t491/serendipochi/output_zps7b42ef79.png)

[Database Screenshot](http://i1062.photobucket.com/albums/t491/serendipochi/database_zpsc8b13cbc.png)

---

I am doing this for my thesis. Really appreciate any help.

Thanks a lot~

Comment: Why are you using `HashMap` instead of a regular `List<String>`?

Comment: @vinitius I haven't tried using `List<String>`. Been using `HashMap` following my professor's lessons. Sorry. Can you enlighten me how to implement it using `List<String>` please?

Comment: Please check this tutorial --> http://www.learn2crack.com/2013/11/listview-from-json-example.html

Comment: @FarshadKazemi If I am using `private String[] drinkImages = {
        "http://webitprojects.com/restaurant/images/drinks/drk_coffee.jpg",
        "http://webitprojects.com/restaurant/images/drinks/drk_calamansijuice.jpg",
        "http://webitprojects.com/restaurant/images/drinks/drk_blackgulaman.jpg",
        "http://webitprojects.com/restaurant/images/drinks/drk_avocadoshake.jpg",
        "http://webitprojects.com/restaurant/images/drinks/drk_durianshake.jpg" };` I'm getting the listview correctly. So what I am trying to do is just to replace it with data from db but with the same output.

Comment: @serendipochi, Which database is your mean ?1 SQLite(in your project) or MySQL (from server) ?!

Comment: @FarshadKazemi I am using MySQL. I don't have problem retrieving from MySQL database using JSON - my logcat's output is correct. I just want to replace the values of `String[ ] drinkImages from the values (still URLs) I retrieved from MySQL.

Comment: What's the `url image` attribute in your json?

Comment: @vinitius This? `String drk_image = c.getString(TAG_DRK_IMAGE);`

Comment: @serendipochi, In your **LazyAdapter**, you didn't get **TAG_DRK_IMAGE**! Also in **Lazy_ListItem**, you didn't add this line in **onCreate** method --> new LoadAllProducts().execute();

Comment: @serendipochi but you're not using it in `doInBackground()`

Comment: @vinitius I did use it in `map.put(TAG_DRK_IMAGE, drk_image);`.

Comment: This post may provide same help .... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/541966/lazy-load-of-images-in-listview?rq=1

Comment: @FarshadKazemi Oh yes, I forgot to add `new LoadAllProducts().execute();` - Thank you for pointing that out. But what do you mean I didn't get `TAG_DRK_IMAGE` in **Lazy_Adapter**? My **Lazy_Adapter** parameter is `Lazy_Adapter(Activity a, String[] d)` where `String[] d` is `String[] drinkImages` from **Lazy_ListItem**. That's why I need to pass the value from the `HashMap` to `String[] drinkImages`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you are using **AsyncTask**, maybe your task isn't finished yet.
So, you should add your adapter instance and assign it to your listview in **onPostExecute** method.

Please change your LazyListItem.java looklike below code:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class Lazy_ListItem extends Activity {

ListView list;
Lazy_Adapter adapter;
// Creating JSON Parser object
JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> drinksList;
// url to get all drinks list
private static String url_all_drinks =  "http://10.0.2.2/restosnapp/get_all_products.php";

// JSON Node names
private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
private static final String TAG_DRINKS = "drinks";
private static final String TAG_DRK_IMAGE = "drk_image";

// Your Images Array
private String[] drinkImages;

// drinks JSONArray
JSONArray drinks = null;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.list_item);

list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
new LoadAllProducts().execute();

}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
list.setAdapter(null);
super.onDestroy();
}

/**
* Background Async Task to Load all drinks by making HTTP Request
* */
class LoadAllProducts extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

/**
 * getting All drinks from url
 * */
protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
    // Building Parameters
    List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    // getting JSON string from URL
    JSONObject json = jParser.makeHttpRequest(url_all_drinks, "GET",
            params);

    // Check your log cat for JSON response
    Log.d("All Drinks: ", json.toString());

    try {
        // Checking for SUCCESS TAG
        int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

        if (success == 1) {
            // drinks found
            // Getting Array of Drinks
            drinks = json.getJSONArray(TAG_DRINKS);

            // Define Lenght for Images Array
            drinkImages = new String[drinks.length()];

            // looping through All Drinks
            for (int i = 0; i < drinks.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject c = drinks.getJSONObject(i);

                // Storing each json item in variable
                String drk_image = c.getString(TAG_DRK_IMAGE);

                // Add image into Array
                drinkImages[i] = drk_image;
                // creating new HashMap
                HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                map.put(TAG_DRK_IMAGE, drk_image);

                // adding HashList to ArrayList
                drinksList.add(map);

            }
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return null;
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    adapter = new Lazy_Adapter(this, drinkImages);
    list.setAdapter(adapter);
    super.onPostExecute(result);
}
}
```

Comment: I am getting "The constructor Lazy_Adapter(Lazy_ListItem.LoadAllProducts, String[]) is undefined" on line `adapter = new Lazy_Adapter(this, drinkImages);` on **onPostExecute**. :/

Comment: Sorry, Please change **this**  to  **Lazy_ListItem.this**

Comment: You forgot to add `drinksList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();` on **onCreate**, but it's working now. Yay! Thank you so much for your help, especially for your patience. I really appreciate it!

Comment: @serendipochi, your welcome. hope you catch top score from professor's lessons ...

Comment: *crossfingers* I hope you keep on sharing your knowledge to others who are in need, too. Thank you again!